# django model.meta equivalent in entity framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am trying to figure out relationship information during runtime of a generic entity object such as which of its fields are many-to-many. In Django, this is easily done using Model.meta. Is there an equivalent in EntityFramework?

Comment: You can use reflections in c# to figure out the type of object at runtime and then you can compare if certain field are present to make decisions on entity relations. A better solution might exist.

Comment: @inthevortex I was thinking the same thing, but it seems like it's not so easy to determine relationships from properties at runtime. Do you have a sample?

Comment: do you mind if I give uncompiled code, for now, of the exact things you need to do?

Comment: sure that's fine. Atleast I'll get an idea as I'm not really sure how to determine if a related property is a model and if it's many to many.

Answer (score 0):

Consider you have the following classes.

```
public class A
    {
        public int MyPropertyA1 { get; set; }
        public string MyPropertyA2 { get; set; }

        public ICollection<B> MyPropertyA3 { get; set; }
    }

    public class B
    {
        public int MyPropertyB1 { get; set; }
        public string MyPropertyB2 { get; set; }
    }
```

So according to this, A to B is a one to many relationship. If you find that the particular object is of A, you can try to check if a particular member is present or not and if present whether it is of type `ICollection<>` or not.

That can be tried in the following way

`var x = obj.GetType().GetProperty("MyPropertyA3").GetType().Name;`

`var x = obj.GetType().GetRuntimeProperty("MyPropertyA3").GetType().Name;`

You can try playing around with types and reflections for the matter of fact. This is a simple snippet to understand the things. The first one doesn't use reflection, but the second one does.